# Spark Scala : Join two Dataframes by near position and time range

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two Dataframe :

1. A Dataframe `DF1` with structure like :  `(ID, StartDate, EndDate, Position)`
2. a Dataframe `DF2` that look like : `(DateTime, Position)`

I want to use those Dataframes to create a new one, that contains for each DF1(ID), the number of rows in DF2 where DF2(DateTime) is between DF1(StartDate) and DF1(EndDate) and DF2(Position) is near DF1(Position)

We can assume I have a udf function `isNearUDF(pos1,pos2)` that does the job to comparate positions.

I'm currently trying to do this with a join between my dataframes, but it does not seems to be the right solution

EDIT 2:

Here is a MVCE :

```
def isInRadius(lat1:Double,lon1:Double,lat2:Double,lon2:Double,dist:Double):Boolean={
  val distance = 0// calculate distance between lon/lat positions

  return distance<=dist
}

val DF1 = sc.parallelize(Array(
  ("ID1", "2018-02-27T13:47:59.416+01:00", "2018-03-01T16:02:00.632+01:00", "25.13297154663", "55.13297154663"),
  ("ID2", "2018-02-25T13:47:59.416+01:00", "2018-02-07T16:02:00.632+01:00", "26.13297154663", "55.13297154663"),
  ("ID3", "2018-02-24T13:47:59.416+01:00", "2018-02-02T16:02:00.632+01:00", "25.13297154663", "55.13297154663")
// ...
)).toDF("ID", "CreationDate","EndDate","Lat1","Lon1")

val DF2 = sc.parallelize(Array(
  ("2018-02-27T13:47:59.416+01:00","25.13297154663", "55.13297154663"),
  ("2018-02-27T13:47:59.416+01:00","25.1304663", "54.10663"),
  ("2018-02-27T13:47:59.416+01:00","25.1354663", "55.132904663")
  // ...
)).toDF("DateTime","Lat2","Lon2")

val isInRadiusUdf = udf(isInRadius _)

val DF3 = DF1.join(DF2,$"DateTime">=$"CreationDate" && $"DateTime"<=$"EndDate" /*&& isInRadiusUdf($"Lat1",$"Lon1",$"Lat2",$"Lon2",lit(10))*/)

display(DF3)
```

That work for dates, but take a long time.
When I add the isInRadius condition, I get the error :

```
SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task not serializable: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader
```

Comment: Why a join isn´t a good solution?

Comment: I can't manage to use my UDF function while doing a join, I will provide an example of my code.
Moreover, the join while checking if the DateTime is in the timerange take a lot of time

Comment: without joining you won't be able to perform udf function on both dataframes at once. You don't have to perform udf function if you apply the logic while joining

Comment: provide us the samples of both dataframes with schema and expected output

Comment: We need a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please !

Comment: I added the MVCE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying various possible solutions and getting weird result, I finally managed to solve my problem by simply restarting my Spark Cluster (Databricks Notebook)
I have absolutely no idea what was the problem but the code of the MVCE work now.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your function definition to:

```
def isInRadius : Double => Double => Double => Double => Double = lat1 => long1 => lat2 => long2 => dist {
  val distance = // calculate distance between lon/lat positions

  return distance<=dist
}
```

Comment: What is different with this syntax ?
When I try this I get 2 errors : 
error: not found: value dist
def isInRadius : Double => Double => Double => Double => Double = lat1 => long1 => lat2 => long2 => dist {
                                                                                                    

error: not found: value dist
  return distance<=dist